# am I fecthing it wrong? FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php

am I fecthing it wrong? I'm using FETCH_ASSOC
It is not working, can someone help me please? I don't know whats wrong with it
this is my code

```
 if(!empty($_POST)){
        if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] > 0){
            $id=$_POST['id'];
            GetSuppliersView();
        }
    }
    function GetSuppliersView() {
        global $db;
        global $id;
        try{
            $query = $db->query("
   SELECT
        suppliers.*,
        third_party_services.name as servicename
    FROM
        suppliers
    INNER JOIN
        suppliers_services
    ON
        suppliers.id = suppliers_services.supplier_id
    LEFT JOIN
        third_party_services
    ON
        suppliers_services.id = third_party_services.id
    WHERE
        suppliers_services.supplier_id = $id
            ");
            $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $result['success'] = true;
            $result['result'] = $row;
            echo json_encode($result);
        return true;
        } catch (PDOException $pe) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

can you help me please?

Comment: Where did the `$result` came from?

Comment: I think you meant `$result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and not `$row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: turn on error reporting to find out

Comment: Fair warning: By trusting `POST` input for `$id`, **you are vulnerable to SQL injection**. As you are using PDO, it is recommend you switch to using [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) rather than the `query` method.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Person');
$row = $query->fetch();
```

instead of this

```
$row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```